# FACEBOOK GRAPH API : Error while trying to access user information

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.6

I am trying to make a GET request to facebook graph API. When i introduce locale,timezone and gender to the below URL, I receive an error -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/USER_ID?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

error   
message "(#100) Insufficient permission to access user profile."
type    "OAuthException"
code    100
error_subcode   2018247
fbtrace_id  "EcbnYPgb/sm"
```

Please help as I am unable to understand why that would be the case.

Answer (score 3):

It's your inclusion of `locale,timezone,gender` which is causing this error.

According to [Facebook's recent changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/), for apps created after July 26, 2018 to access additional user profile fields app developers must apply for each field in the Messenger Platform tab of the app console.